# Indexing a dynamic order by statement

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, rails-postgresql

I've got a SQL query I'm running in PostgreSQL that looks along the lines of this: (ActiveRecord generated so apologies if it's not as optimized as it could be)

```
SELECT DISTINCT items.id,
   CASE WHEN items.marker is not null
          THEN (items.rating - (educations.cards_done - items.marker))
        WHEN items.marker is null
          THEN 0 
   END AS order
FROM items
INNER JOIN educations ON educations.item_id = items.id 
WHERE items.active = true
ORDER BY 
   CASE WHEN items.marker is not null
          THEN (items.rating - (educations.cards_done - items.marker))
        WHEN items.marker is null
          THEN 0 
   END
LIMIT 10
```

Is it possible to have an index on that order by with the case statement in PostgreSQL?  If not, is there any other way to possibly speed up this query?
Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

You can start by optimizing the CASE statement itself. The 2nd `WHEN` is redundant. There can only ever be two cases (`NULL` and `NOT NULL`). Simplify:

```
CASE WHEN items.marker is not null 
     THEN ((items.rating + items.marker) - educations.cards_done)
ELSE 0 END
```

AS far as **indexing** is concerned, I do not know of a way to use values from more than one table in an index. You would have to use a [materialized view](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view) or a redundant column in one of the tables for that, which could be updated by triggers. I would only think about such a thing, if `ORDER` performance is very important and the tables involved are mostly read and rarely written to.

I assume you already have indexes on `educations.item_id` AND on `items.id`? (Primary key is an automatic index, foreign key is **not**.)

Depending on the percentage of items with `active = true` a partial index on `items` might help. Active items would have to be a minority for that to work.

```
CREATE INDEX foo_idx ON items(id) WHERE active;
```

Test with [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html) if indexes get used in your query. If you select large portions of the involved tables, sequential scans will be faster anyway and indexes not used.